# ESLint Rule on React Component: Method Render expected no return value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I can't for the life of me understand why anyone would even want this rule let alone what it means.  I **want** to return something here in the render

```
export default class SearchTabs extends Component {
  render() {
    const { panels, selectedTab } = this.props;
    if (!panels || panels.length === 0) return;

    let filter = null;

    const tabs = panels.member.map((panel, idx) => {
      const { id: panelId, headline } = panel;
      const url = getHeaderLogo(panel, 50);
      const item = url ?
        <img src={url} alt={headline} /> : headline;
      const classname = classNames([
        searchResultsTheme.tabItem,
        (idx === selectedTab) ? searchResultsTheme.active : null,
      ]);

      filter = (idx === selectedTab) ? this.renderFilters(panel) : filter;

      return (
        <TabItem
          classname={`${classname} search-tab`}
          headline={headline}
          idx={idx}
          content={item}
          onclick={() => {
            this.tabChanged(idx, headline);
          }}
          panelId={panelId}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className={searchResultsTheme.filters}>
        <ul className={`${searchResultsTheme.tabs} ft-search-tabs`}>{tabs}</ul>
        <div className={searchResultsTheme.dropdown}>{filter}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In the future it would be good to include the full error message in the question itself, since you only actually mention the error in the title, and the error itself would have a nice line number included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is the line

```
if (!panels || panels.length === 0) return;
```

It's complaining because this code path does not return anything. Try changing it to

```
if (!panels || panels.length === 0) return null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Regardless the other answers - the problem is caused by the `consistent-return` eslint, which makes sure that every function that you have will always have the same return option:

```
function doSomething(condition) {

    if (condition) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return;                   /*error Expected a return value.*/
    }
}

function doSomething(condition) {

    if (condition) {
        return;
    } else {
        return true;              /*error Expected no return value.*/
    }
}

function doSomething(condition) { /*error Expected to return a value at the end of this function.*/

    if (condition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It makes sense in languages like javascript that you can't force a function to return specific type/make sure it always return something (not undefined) and such.

More information can be found here:
https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/consistent-return

In your specific code - you have 3 return options. 2 of them return jsx and 1 return undefined, which caused this specific eslint-error.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of this, `if (!panels || panels.length === 0) return;`. EsLint warns if return types are ambiguous because this returns undefined and later a ReactDom object.

simply `if (!panels || panels.length === 0) return null;` and it should be fine.